# How to find all Typescript project re-exported types

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am running into this issue [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/603), and need to fix all instances of re-exported types in my TS angular 2 project. The only issue I face is I have no idea where these problems arise from when webpack compiles. It throws this:

`ERROR in /blueocean/modules/client/dist/app-aot/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (9,9): Cannot re-export a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided`

But the stack trace does not point to project source code. Is there a way to easily search for re-export problems in my project? I would very much like to reduce develop build time.

Comment: Um isn't `/blueocean/modules/client/dist/app-aot/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts` this the source of the error ? It would seem so to me.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I suppose it depends on what 'source of the error' is defined as. Yes the source is coming from the angular package but the cause of this error is that there are re-exported types somewhere in the app source code, which I need to find and address.